# Page Fault of 1,000,000 in 64 GB RAM Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance, memory

I have a 64 bit Machine that runs SQL Server. It has 64 GB RAM.

It is giving around 1,000,000 Page Faults per second. Is it OK or it is giving too many Page Faults? if the number is hign the what should I do to resolve this problem?

Thanks for your help..

Comment: How big are your databases?

Comment: We would need more information in order to answer this question (why are the page faults happening: Are you running other software? Is your DB just *that* big?, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

This means that 1 b times per sec, sql requires access to a memory space that is mapped in the OS, but not yet loaded in physical memory (still on disk)
So there are possibly a very high I/o too ("hi" column in "top").

It's difficult to answer how to fix this, I'm no SQL expert, but this is clearly sub-optimal.